# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema (Webpack 5)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am running into trouble when configuring Webpack 5. Here is the error message that I come across during the `npm run serve` command within the CLI:

```
╰─$ npm run serve

> e-portfolio@1.0.0 serve
> webpack-dev-server --mode=development

[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[2].loader should be a non-empty string.
      -> A loader request.
```

Below are the relevant files:

```
*webpack.config.js*

const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss?$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 5500,
    watchContentBase: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
}
```

```
*package.json*

{
  "name": "e-portfolio",
  "description": "I'm currently working on building an E-Portfolio using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The purpose of working on this project is to further imporve my current skills using the above technologies in order to confidently use them alongside more advance technologies, libraries and/or frameworks.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
    "deploy": "npm run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/e-portfolio.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/e-portfolio/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/BIGWALDOR/e-portfolio#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this on my own. I made the following changes:

```
*webpack.config.js*

const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        **use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],**
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?/,
        **use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],**
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss?/,
        **use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ],**
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)?$/,
        **use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png',
            },**
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    **static: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),**
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
  ],
}
```